# Duplicate Data when I retrieve the data from file in C++

Tags: c++, file, vector, fstream, getline

First of all, there's an data inside my file...

```
1|Malaysia|UK|One-Way|20|6|20|6|2000|12|12|12|12|12|
```

The above data is the data inside my file

But when I cout the data, there's an duplicate data...

```
1|Malaysia|UK|One-Way|20|6|20|6|2000|12|12|12|12|12|
1|Malaysia|UK|One-Way|20|6|20|6|2000|12|12|12|12|12|
```

So what's the problem when I cout the data???
Here's the code....

```
void Flight::displayFlight(vector <Flight> &flightProfile)
{
string readFlightID, readPrice, readBusinessList, readBusinessWaitingList, readEconomicList,            readEconomicWaitingList;
flightProfile.erase(flightProfile.begin(),flightProfile.end());
ifstream inFlight("Flight.txt");
if(inFlight.fail()) return;
while(!(inFlight.eof()))
{
    getline(inFlight,readFlightID,'|');
    istringstream(readFlightID)>>flightID;
    getline(inFlight,departure,'|');
    getline(inFlight,destination,'|');
    getline(inFlight,flightType,'|');
    getline(inFlight,readBusinessList,'|');
    istringstream(readBusinessList)>>businessList;
    getline(inFlight,readBusinessWaitingList,'|');
    istringstream(readBusinessWaitingList)>>businessWaitingList;
    getline(inFlight,readEconomicList,'|');
    istringstream(readEconomicList)>>economicList;
    getline(inFlight,readEconomicWaitingList,'|');
    istringstream(readEconomicWaitingList)>>economicWaitingList;
    getline(inFlight,readPrice,'|');
    istringstream(readPrice)>>price;
    getline(inFlight, day,'|');
    getline(inFlight, month,'|');
    getline(inFlight, year,'|');
    getline(inFlight, hour,'|');
    getline(inFlight, min,'|');
    inFlight.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout<<flightID<<departure<<destination<<flightType<<businessList<<businessWaitingList<<economicList<<economicWaitingList<<price<<day<<month<<year<<hour<<min<<endl;
}
inFlight.close();
}
```

Comment: When I saw the word "duplicate" in the question, I knew this would be `eof()`-abuse before opening it.

Comment: @KerrekSB LOL...What it means?

Comment: `eof()` does not mean what you think and doesn't work the way you think. You'll find literally thousands of similar questions on this website, or you could always read the manual yourself...

Comment: @KerrekSB To be fair you will also find 1000's of tutorials, sample codes etc. telling you that this is this right way to read from a file. The idea seems so persistent, despite it being easily demonstrated to be wrong, that I think this has to go down as a bad piece of API design. People just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (and others) common mistake is that the eof-bit is only set on input operations (RTFM).

The correct way to read a file line by line would be to do:

```
if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **always** need to check **after** you read from a stream if the stream is in a good state! If reading of the data failed, e.g., because the end of the stream was reached, the stream will be in a fail state. For example

```
while (std::getline(inFlight, readFlightID)
       && std::istringstream(readFlightId) >> flightID
       && std::getline(inFlight, departure)
       ...
       ) {
    // now process the read data
}
```

BTW, note that the trick using a temporary stream only works like this if the target type is a member of `std::istream`. If it is not, you'll need to extra a reference from the stream, e.g. using

```
std::istringstream("some text") >> std::skipws >> value
```

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to put all of this in the condition of the `while`?  Given his format, I'd use `boost::split` on the line, but in any case, I'd keep the reading of the line separate, in order to recover from errors and stay synchronized.  (Think of the mess if one of the lines has one less field, for some reason.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, I wouldn't really consider it a good idea to read an integer into a `std::string` and then decode the `std::string` in a `std::istringstream`. However, I just followed the format of the original code. The important part is that all input attempts are checked to see if they were successful. ... and, yes, I typically do that in one condition although it is normally fairly simple because I'd create input operator for different structures.

Comment: Defining application specific types and having them overload `>>` is certainly the preferred solution.  But for line oriented input, you definitely want to read line by line (and keep track of the line number), in order to display the line number in your error messages, and in order to resynchronize, and not stop processing on the first error.  This can be done without using `getline` and `istringstream`, but for an inexperienced programmer, the `getline`/`istringstream` solution is certainly the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not checking that your `getline` succeeds.
The last time through the loop, it probably fails (because
you've read all of the data), so you pick up the old values.

This is *not* the way to read line based input.  For starters,
line based input should be read line by line:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( inFlight, line ) ) {
    //  Parse line here...
}
```

There are many ways to parse the line.  One of the most common
solutions is to put it into an `std::istringstream` and read
from that.  That's probably overkill for what you're doing,
however; you need probably something like `boost::split` (which
you can knock up in less than an hour if you can't use Boost).

At any rate, `while ( !someIStream.eof() )` is never correct.

Two other quick comments: you shouldn't define your variables
before you need them, and there's no real point in closing
`inFlight` if it's immediately going out of scope.